# Android notification message at a particular time why it is repeated every time the app launched

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I would like to make the app send a notification at specific time of a day, I need to use alarm manger with notification as what described by this [tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/).

The code is working well, and send the notification at the specified time even if the app is not running however the notification is send also any time I run the app which is very weird.. below is the code, thanks for any hint.

inside `onCreate()` in `MainActivity`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 33);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM); 

Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
   context.startService(service1);

}

}
```

**MyAlarmService**

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service
{

   private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
       super.onCreate();
    }

   @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access"})
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {

       mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);




       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

      PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Today 27-5-2014")
            .setContentText(" You have your last final exam ")
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);


       mManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

please note that my requirement is to send notification at particular time say At 10:00 Am.. 
The code above succeed in sending the notification at 10:00 AM, 
My problem is that the notification is still fired every time I run the app even if it is not 10:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

Try out following code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Calendar calendar;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+60*06*24*1000;

    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, 0);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, alarmIntent);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60*60*24, alarmIntent);
}
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
Intent in;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Notification mBuilder;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    in=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);

    mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Your Title")
        .setContentText("Your Text")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder);
    mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder);
}
}
```

Include following code in your manifest file

```
 <application>
    ....
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/> 
  </application>
```

Easy Tutorial of AlarmManager [here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html)...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is already in the manifest file. Thanks Rohit.

Comment: it gives an error in define NotificationManager inside BroadcastReceiver child I tried    mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); but gives an error.

Comment: @user2814778: Code Updated... Plz try it.... If it satisfies plz dnt 4get to mark answer..

Comment: @user2814778: In your code you are using `alarmManager.set(...)` method. If you use `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60*60*24, alarmIntent);' will repeat alarm daily after 1000*06*60*24 milliseconds means after 24 hrs.

Comment: when I use alarmManager.setRepeating in my code; it is not showing the notification until the specified time up even if I run the app before, However the problem is still if I run the app after, it is show the notification every run.. very weird.. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2814778: Whatever time you give in `alarmManager.setRepeating`, it will be repeated after that time infinity. If you are setting your calender to particular time and telling it to repeat after 24 hrs it will repeat after 24 hrs no matter what you launch the app or not. If you want to reduce time you can in same method. But time should be in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below to produce alarm every 24 hours. It works fine but when you launch the App the first time you will see the notification. But later on it wont produce notification when you open the App.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

        boolean testval = (pendingIntent == null);

        if(testval)
        {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        }
```